# keep inclueded layout at the bottom of parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have LinearLayout that save in a separate file and use it with `Include`.
The problem is that i want this layout at the bottom of screen. its fine in my first layout that i use RelativeLayout in it . but in the second layout i used LinearLayout and it seems  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` doesnt work in it. how can i fix this ?
Here is my code:
**Included layout:**
    `

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@id/lytButtons"
                  style="@style/Register.LayoutButtons"
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>`
```

In first layout i have RelativeLayout and in the second one i have LinearLayout. How can i change my included part that keep it at the bottom in both of RelativeLayout and  LinearLayout?

Comment: `it seems  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" doesnt work`. No, it does **not**. It only works in a **RelativeLayout** parent.

Comment: For `LinearLayout` use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

Comment: Right and its my problem here. How can i fix it for linearLayout ?

Comment: Have you read my comment?

Comment: @PiyushGupta is correct!  were do you use include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to include this layout in a parent layout, just specify where it should go :

```
<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/yourLayout" />
```

EDIT following Piyush Gupta comment : if the parent layout is going to be a linearLayout, just replace the alignParentBottom :

```
<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    layout="@layout/yourLayout" />
```

Comment: OP wants to include in `LinearLayout`. Works well for `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: try it but doesnt work :/ let me work abit more in it . i will use your idea and if i resolve it i will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

to solve your confusion i am giving you sample code to add footer

Footer layout:footer_layout.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Footer Layout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Just simple textview to show as footer .

Main Layout:activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        layout="@layout/footer_layout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:
[image]

Let me know still any query.